# How to isolate an object or drawing when scanning?

Tags: scanning

For instance, when I cut out a speech bubble and scan it, there is a whitish background; I want to get rid of this without using an image manipulation program.

Are there setting that I have to change while scanning to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really about photography. It's probably more appropriate for the Graphic Design SE.

Answer (score 2):

As far as a I know it's impossible. Scanners have a white 'background' that will be scanned as part of the image.

It might be possible, if your scanning software allows it, to use a green or blue background that is then treated as transparent, similar to the use of chroma key:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key

Otherwise it has to be done in a second program but using the same technique.